# How I make role-based authorization

Tags: c#

ı am asking a new question about this, because my question is closed. I am new member in this site, so ı did not know how can ı ask good question.

I am working on my project. I want to use role based authorization for this project but i did not. What should i do , what should i research?

for example the program has an input interface, I will check if this information is correct from there, then this user will have the administrator, editor, etc. and for example the administrator can use anything in the program but editor can not use some functions such as delete or update, so I want them to do something according to their role authorization.

Comment: Did you try looking up how to do role based authorization in the framework of your choice? Web Forms, MVC, Core MVC, Razor Pages, Blazor....whatever it is.

Comment: Hi @notcontrol, welcome to StackOverflow! This is a website where we help you debug your code. This kind of open-ended question would be better suited in another forum. Please look here on how to ask a better question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your last question was also closed for the same reason, so I would really suggest looking at my link.

Answer (score -1):

First all you will have to create additional tables for your extended role management like projects and there relationship with the users in context of operations, which might be your controller's actions.

One way of doing is to create your own table for roles. In that case you will only use only Asp net membership users, but it all depends your requirements.

Secondly you have to handle it in MVC, In my opinion the best way is to implement it through your own custom Authorization attribute, and decorate your controller's actions with your custom authorization attribute instead of [Authorization] attribute.

Its very simple.

```
[CustomAuthorize]
//[Authorize]
public ActionResult GetProjectTasks(string projectname)
{

}
```

Comment: You just assumed this question was about ASP.NET MVC? Probably not a safe assumption.